# How do I view Windows Azure Analytics

Tags: .net, azure, cloud, azure-analytics

I've been running some background processes using the Worker role in Azure to test out Azure to see if it something I can consider for one of my projects.  When I click on the Analytics tab, I get a message saying "Coming soon.". Is there any way for me to determine some metrics?

I'm mostly interested in trying to calculate a potential monthly cost for my programs.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the new analytics system isn't available yet.  If you're trying to estimate costs, note that CPU usage is easy to count (number of role instances * number of hours they've been running * $0.12), and storage usage is even easier (GB * months * $0.15).

Bandwidth will be a hard one to estimate without analytics, sorry they're not available yet.

Comment: when you say "number of hours running", if I have a thread that runs every hour (lets say that it runs for 1 second each time), would my CPU usage for 1 day be 24 * .12 or do I count the time the thread is sleeping?

Comment: You count the time the thread is sleeping.  (It's wall-clock-time, not CPU usage.)